# enable/disable menu items in xcode

Tags: xcode, menu

My app has a main window with some graphics and a hud panel for adjusting stuff on the main window. I use a menu heading called "Adjustments" to bring up the hud, and hide it away when no longer needed. This all works fine. Now to the "easy" part.
I have 2 items under the "Adjustment" heading (which is the second heading up top, index=1) : "Show Adjustments" to open the (hud) adjustment panel with all the sliders, and "Hide Adjustments" to close the window.  I thought that I should dim the "Hide Adjustment" item until the panel was opened, and then hide the "Show Adjustments" item until the panel was closed. I'm having some difficulty doing this even after reading all about NSMenu, NSMenuItem, etc.
In my awakeFromNib file, I have :

```
rootMenu = [NSApp mainMenu];  
[rootMenu setAutoenablesItems:NO];  
[[rootMenu itemWithTag:11] setEnabled:YES];// I set the Tag for "Show .." in IB to 11  
[[rootMenu itemWithTag:12] setEnabled:NO];//  I set the tag for "Hide .." in IB to 12
```

which does nothing !

In my IBAction "function" connected to the "Show Adjustments" item I have :

```
[self orderFront:nil]; // which opens the hud
```

// but this stuff doesn't dim the first drop-down menu item :

```
[[rootMenu itemWithTag:11]  setEnabled:NO];// doesn't do anything  
[[rootMenu itemWithTag:12]  setEnabled:YES];// doesn't do anything  
[[rootMenu itemAtIndex:0]  setEnabled:NO];// dims the "quit" menu - un-guideline-like, I know, I know !
```

If I add this :

```
[[rootMenu itemAtIndex:1]  setEnabled:NO]; // both items dim, so I think I'm close !
```

I can dim both of the drop down items, but of course I only want to dim one of them at a time !
How do I refer to the individual items ? I thought "itemWithTag" would work, but so far it has not.

I need to do the equivalent of MENU 2,1,0 and MENU 2,2,1 in Futurebasic if that helps.

(BTW, in case you can't tell, I'm not yet up to speed on all these objects !)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the menu hierarchy. I now realize that the drop-down is a submenu, and the items in it can be controlled like this :

```
menuItem = [rootMenu itemAtIndex:1];  
subMenu = [menuItem submenu];  
[[subMenu itemWithTag:11] setEnabled:YES];  
[[subMenu itemWithTag:12] setEnabled:NO];
```